# Replace words in haskell

Tags: haskell, str-replace

I want to replace full words in text. Type definition is: `replace :: [(String, String)] -> String -> String`. Function example is:

```
replace [("fox", "cat"), ("he", "she")] "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
-- result: "The quick brown cat jumps over the lazy dog"`
```

It should be with functions `words` and `unwords`.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Have [you tried anything yet](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)? If so, what were your problems, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I dont know how can I save words into something after I used function "words".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Understanding the assignment

Your assignment says that you should use `words` and `unwords`:

```
words   :: String -> [String]
unwords :: [String] -> String
```

It is therefore clear, that you need something to operate on a list of Strings:

```
innerFunc :: [String] -> [String]
```

This will enable you to use `unwords . innerFunc . words`. However, that looks just like mapping over Strings with a correct replacement function:

```
innerFunc = map f
```

where `f` should be something like

```
f :: String -> String
```

So it's enough if you manage to create a function that replaces **a single word correctly**.

## Solving the assignment

As stated above, we're now looking for a function that replaces a single word correctly. For convenience, lets create a type synonym `Word`*, so we know whether this is currently meant for a single word or a whole sentence.

<sup>* note that Haskell provides `Word` already in `Data.Word`, but that is something completely different, namely a unsigned `Int` variant, so it's just for convenience in the following code</sup>

```
type Word = String
```

### Replace a single word by a single replacement patterns

Lets start very simple. We shall write a function that works only for a single word:

```
replaceSimple :: (Word, Word) -> Word -> Word
replaceSimple (orig, repl) word = if orig == word then repl else word
```

It's clear that this will replace `word` iff `orig == word`:

```
replaceSimple ("fox", "cat") "fox" == "cat"
replaceSimple ("fox", "cat") "dog" == "dog"
```

### Replace a single word by a many replacement patterns

Now we want to use that knowledge for a function that still operates on a single Word, but takes it replacements from a list and applies the first one that matches:

```
replaceSingle :: [(Word, Word)] -> Word -> Word
replaceSingle []     word = word
replaceSingle (r:rs) word = if word == fst r then snd r else replaceMany rs word
```

Look closely: `replaceSingle` will leave the word unchanged iff the list of replacements is empty or there's a identitiy replacement like `("fox","fox")` before any other replacement. Otherwise it's going to exchange `word` with the replacement if they match or try the rest of the replacement rules.

### Putting things together

Now `replaceSingle` almost looks like `f` above, doesn't it? And it sure is! All you need to provide is the list of replacements:

```
:t replaceSingle [("fox","cat"),("he","she")]
replaceSingle [("fox","cat"),("he","she")] :: String -> String
```

All you need to do is to `map` this function as written above.

Putting together the functions `map`, `replaceSingle`, `unwords` and `words` is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thank you very much for exhaustive answer!

Answer (score 1):

For text manipulation in modern Haskell is generally recommended to not use the `String` type and instead use the [`text`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) package. If for some reason you are starting with `String`s, you can convert them to `Text` with [`pack`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.1.0.0/docs/Data-Text.html#v%3apack).  Then, with [`replace`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.1.0.0/docs/Data-Text.html#v%3areplace) function that allows you to do something like this:

```
>>> :set -XOverloadedStrings
>>> import Data.Text
>>> replace "he" "she" . replace "fox" "cat" $ "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
"Tshe quick brown cat jumps over tshe lazy dog"
```

If for some reason you are stuck with your original type signature here is a way to implement it:

```
>>> import Data.Monoid
>>> import Data.Foldable
>>> import Control.Monad
>>> import Control.Arrow
>>> let replace' l = unpack . appEndo (foldMap (Endo . uncurry replace . join (***) pack) l) . pack
>>> :t replace'
replace' :: Foldable t => t (String, String) -> String -> String
>>> replace' [("he","she"), ("fox","cat")] "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
"Tshe quick brown cat jumps over tshe lazy dog"
```

Comment: He isn't stuck to the original signature, but to `words` and `unwords`.

Comment: @Zeta, alright, I didn't understand that using `words` and `unwords` was a requirement, I took it as (misleading) hint. I have difficulties imagining a real scenario with such a constrain. Maybe if you don't want to depend on `text`, but even then, it may not be needed to use `words` or `unwords`.

Comment: @DannyNavarro: As newcomers to a language might have difficulties with `Monoid`, `Foldable`, `Monad` and `Arrow`. Even though it's not very efficient, it's simple to understand `unwords . map myReplacement . words`, much simpler than `unpack . appEndo ...`. That's what assignment and constrains are for - learning a language step by step.

Comment: @Zeta, well, I view it differently. If a newcomer comes with `word` `unwords` on his own instead of `Endo`, I agree with you, it's alright. I even think it's OK giving the hint about `words` and `unwords`, but make it a requirement makes it too artificial for a real case scenario. In real life being constrained with a type signature is much more frequent than being constrained by some functions someone has told you must use.